# Is it possible to wait for a keypress using waitForFunction in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I am trying to wait for a keypress, as opposed to a timeout or a navigation. I think this is possible with `page.waitForFunction()`, but my own implementations have been unsuccessful.

I have tried:

```js
  addKeydown("keydown");
      function addKeydown(type) {
        return page.evaluateOnNewDocument((type) => {
          // here we are in the browser context
          let breakout = 0;

          document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            if (e.code === "Enter") {
              breakout = 0;
            }
          });
        }, type);
      }

      await page.waitForFunction("breakout == 1");
```

and

```js
      await page.waitForFunction(() => {
        console.log("trying function");
        let breakout = 1;
        let event = (ev) => {
          if (ev.keyCode == "Enter") {
            breakout = 0;
          }
        };
        document.addEventListener("keydown", event);
        if (breakout) {
          return true;
        }
      });
```

How can I have my puppeteer script wait until I press `enter` to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `let breakout = 0;` defines a non-global variable. If you drop the `let`, you'll get a global variable attached to the `window` object, i.e. `window.breakout = 0;` which is visible to your `waitForFunction` callback. You can debug this by typing the variable name into the browser's console to see if it exists while your script is running--if not, there's a scope issue and future evaluations in browser context won't see the definition.

There's also a couple of typos: your first example's predicate is `breakout == 1` but the keydown handler never sets `breakout` to 1, it just resets it to 0. In the second handler, `breakout = 1` is the default value for a condition `if (breakout)`, and 1 is treated as truthy, giving a false positive. Instead of 1 and 0, I recommend using booleans `false` and `true` and avoiding `===` to rely on the implicit truthiness of `enterPressed` (a clearer name than `breakout`). If you need to use `==`, prefer `===` so no unpredictable type coercion is performed.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.2.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    enterPressed = false;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
      if (e.code === "Enter") {
        enterPressed = true;
      }
    });
  });
  await page.goto("about:blank");

  try {
    await page.waitForFunction("enterPressed");
    console.log("enter was pressed!");
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error("enter was not pressed within the specified timeout");
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```